# React-router, onEnter cause infinite loop with authentication

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I followed this example:

> https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/examples/auth-flow/app.js

I want to prevent users to navigate `login` router after they are `loggedIn`.

I tried to put the `requireAuth` to the `onEnter` of `login` router.

But, when a user access the page for the first time, they are not `loggedIn`,  and it will cause infinite loop.

How can I get out of loop in my case?
here is my code:

```
{
  path: 'login',
  component: Login,
  onEnter: (nextState, replace) => {
    if(!auth.loggined) {
      replace({
        pathname: '/login',
        state: {
          nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname
        }
      })
    } else {
      replace('/')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you possibly share your implementation ?
App.js or `render` function perhaps.

Comment: @keshavDulal update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you trying add `requireAuth` to the `login` page?

I believe your `onEnter` should be like this

```
if(loggedIn){
    replace({
      pathname: '/'
    })
}
```

and nothing more, if you want to prevent access to this page for authenticated users.

Comment: Yeah. the point is when user not loggined. It will always redirect to `/login`, cause infinite loop. I update my question

Comment: @novaline, so why did you add ` replace({ pathname: '/login'})` here? I think this one should be removed from here and then everything will be as you want